# Python 2.7 Dynamic length list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic, list-comprehension

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered. I have done my best to search for a solution with my limited knowledge of terminology.

This is the line of code in question:

```
Matrix = list([s0, s1, s2] for s0 in splits[0] for s1 in splits[1] for s2 in splits[2])
```

Basically, I'm constructing a list (Matrix) with all permutations in the list of lists, "Splits". However, Splits is not always the same size. For instance, sometimes there are 4 columns and the line would look like this:

```
 Matrix = list([s0, s1, s2, **s3**] for s0 in splits[0] for s1 in splits[1] for s2 in splits[2] **for s3 in splits[3]**)
```

How can I make this line adaptive to the length of Splits? I.e.

```
Matrix = list([s0,s1... , sN] for s0 in splits[0] for s1 in splits[1] ... for sN in splits[N])
```

Thank you

Comment: Adding a sample of what splits looks like would help us understand the problem. Even though you say that splits is a list of lists you are only using one index in your statements which raises questions in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Unpack `splits` into the arguments to [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

splits = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# Note: a list of tuples, because product yields tuples
explicit = list((s0, s1, s2) for s0 in splits[0] for s1 in splits[1] for s2 in splits[2])

unpacking = list(product(*splits))

assert explicit == unpacking
```

Comment: Thank you, itertools.product is exactly what I needed.